# What word can "she" be replaced with to refer to family members

Tags: word-usage, usage

What word can you replace *she* with. 
Like if you are talking about mom or grandma or sister.

Comment: why would you want a replacement?

Comment: Can you please explain more specifically what you're asking? I'm guessing there's a construction in your native language that does not exist in English.

Comment: @Catija I suspect OP's language has a wider range of pronouns than English, with different words for persons to whom one stands in different relationships.

Comment: a *bit offensive* but they all can be referred to as 'that lady'...or 'that woman'... instead. My mother tongue has it! :)

Answer (score 4):

Unlike many other languages, English does not employ different pronouns to distinguish formal use from intimate use, or to distinguish degrees of respect or relationship, or anything but gender, number, person and case.

At one time we distinguished singular and plural second-person pronouns, and for a while we also employed this distinction to signify degree of respect; but both uses virtually disappeared from ordinary speech and writing by the end of the 18th century. The singular/plural distinction is still occasionally employed in some religious contexts and in some dialects; but it is no longer associated with degree of respect.

There is also an ancient practice whereby the reigning monarch refers to himself or herself in the plural—"We, Elizabeth, by the Grace of God" addresses "Our trusty and wellbeloved subject N".